# Using a vector as a grep pattern

Tags: r, regex

I am new to R. I am trying to search the columns using `grep` multiple times within an `apply` loop. I use `grep` to specify which rows are summed based on the vector `individuals`

```
individuals <-c("ID1","ID2".....n)
bcdata_total <- sapply(individuals, function(x) {
  apply(bcdata_clean[,grep(individuals, colnames(bcdata_clean))], 1, sum)
})
```

`bcdata` is of random size and contains random data but contains columns that have `individuals` in part of the string

```
>head(bcdata)
  ID1-4 ID1-3 ID2-5
A   3     2    1
B   2     2    3
C   4     5    5
```

`grep(individuals[1],colnames(bcdata_clean))` returns a vector that looks like
 `[1]  1  2`, a list of the column names containing `ID1`. That vector is used to select columns to be summed in `bcdata_clean`. This should occur `n` number of times depending on the length of `individuals`

However this returns the error

```
In grep(individuals, colnames(bcdata)) :
  argument 'pattern' has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
```

And results in all the columns of `bcdata` being identical

Ideally `individuals` would increment each time the function is run like this for each iteration

```
 apply(bcdata_clean[,grep(individuals[1,2....n], colnames(bcdata_clean))], 1, sum)
```

and would result in something like this

```
>head(bcdata_total)
  ID1 ID2
A  5   1
B  4   3 
C  9   5
```

But I'm not sure how to increment `individuals`. What is the best way to do this within the function?

Comment: Please add data using `dput` or something that we can copy and use. Also show expected output for the data shared. Read about [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [how to give a reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269).

Comment: It should be `grep(x, colnames(bcdata_clean))`

Comment: I have edited it to contain some sample data

Comment: @ekoam Ha, thank you so much. That actually helped quite a bit.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `split.default` to split data on similarly named columns and sum them row-wise.

```
sapply(split.default(df, sub('-.*', '', names(df))), rowSums, na.rm. = TRUE)

#  ID1 ID2
#A   5   1
#B   4   3
#C   9   5
```

**data**

```
df <- structure(list(`ID1-4` = c(3L, 2L, 4L), `ID1-3` = c(2L, 2L, 5L
), `ID2-5` = c(1L, 3L, 5L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("A", "B", "C"))
```

Answer (score 0):

Passing `individuals` as my argument in `function(x)` fixed my issue

```
bcdata_total <- sapply(individuals, function(individuals) {
  apply(bcdata_clean[,grep(individuals, colnames(bcdata_clean))], 1, sum)
})
```

Answer (score 0):

An option with `tidyverse`

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(tibble)
df %>%
    rownames_to_column('rn') %>%
    pivot_longer(cols = -rn, names_to = c(".value", "grp"), names_sep="-") %>%
    group_by(rn) %>% 
    summarise(across(starts_with('ID'), sum, na.rm = TRUE), .groups = 'drop') %>%
    column_to_rownames('rn')
#  ID1 ID2
#A   5   1
#B   4   3
#C   9   5
```

#### data

```
df <- df <- structure(list(`ID1-4` = c(3L, 2L, 4L), `ID1-3` = c(2L, 2L, 5L
), `ID2-5` = c(1L, 3L, 5L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("A", "B", "C"))
```